# Multiple Elements in custom SearchParameter

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have an extension where value[x] is sliced into valueCoding and valueDecimal.
I now would like to search on the code provided in the valueCoding and the value in valueDecimal.

Do I need to create two custom SearchParameters or is it possbile to define one, that allows a
request like the following?
http://localhost:4080/Patient?_customSearchParameter.code=ABC&_customSearchParameter.value=111

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each search parameter must have a single search type.  There isn't really a way to search a number in the same way you search a code, so you'll need distinct parameters.  (You can see an example of how this was done for some of the Observation.value search parameters.)